# Error creating conda environment 'r-reticulate' [exit code 1]

Tags: bert-language-model, miniconda, reticulate

I am trying to use BERT in R and for that I need some bits from Python.
However when I try to install transformers, e.g., I am getting the error above.
These are the lines I tried, all failed with the same error:

```
reticulate::py_install('transformers', pip = TRUE)

remotes::install_github("rstudio/reticulate") % installing directly from github

reticulate::install_miniconda(force = TRUE)
```